# Microsecond (or one ms) time resolution on an embedded device (Linux Kernel)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a kernel module I've built that requires at least 1 ms time resolution. I currently use do_gettimeofday() but I'm concerned that this won't work once I move my module to an embedded device. The device has a 180 Mz processor (MIPS) and the default HZ value in the kernel is 100. Thus using jiffies will only give me at best 10 ms resolution. That won't cut it.

What I'd like to know is if do_gettimeofday() is based on the timer interrupt (HZ). Can it be guaranteed to provide at least 1 ms of resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: Embedded systems usually have a bunch of timers available - can you dedicate one of those to your problem?

Comment: Do you need absolute time (e.g. 2010 April 2 8:44:15.12455) with that accuracy?  Or do you just need relative time?  (e.g. 50usec have elapsed)

Comment: Relative time would work as well. I'm not familiar with other ways of keeping track of time other than jiffies and do_gettimeofday. Is there another method I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

ms is not microsecond, it's millisecond.  Without knowing more about your choice of device, no one can possibly answer such an implementation-dependent question as whether gettimeofday is based on the timer interrupt.  If you have chosen a device, which knowing the instruction set and clock speed suggests, then why don't you look at the implementation of that particular kernel to find out?

Comment: You'd probably say "better than 1000 us" in that case.

Answer (score 2):

On an embedded device, it can't be guaranteed.  Seeing as it's MIPS based, it's probably OK, most MIPS machines have cycle counters. But, you're going to have to go read the source to that part of the kernel to see what it is doing on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to enable `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS` in your kernel, and make sure that your platform registers a `clock_event_device`. This is the mechanism that allows to expose high-resolution timers to userspace. You can check the resolution of your timers by calling `clock_getres()` in userspace.